# unify array of a cloned box containing many form fields

Tags: php, jquery

I have this form http://jsfiddle.net/U7Wp2/ which i am posting to this php script

```
<?php
$all = $_POST;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($all);
echo '<pre>';

?>
```

I get the following array

```
<pre>Array
(
    [one] => 1
    [two] => 2
    [three] => 3
    [four] => 4
    [cr_one] => Array
        (
            [0] => aa
            [1] => ee
        )

    [cr_two] => Array
        (
            [0] => bb
            [1] => ff
        )

    [cr_three] => Array
        (
            [0] => cc
            [1] => gg
        )

    [cr_four] => Array
        (
            [0] => dd
            [1] => hh
        )

    [six] => 6
    [seven] => 7
    [eight] => 8
    [kr_one] => Array
        (
            [0] => tt
            [1] => pp
            [2] => er
        )

    [kr_two] => Array
        (
            [0] => rr
            [1] => oo
            [2] => en
        )

    [kr_three] => Array
        (
            [0] => uu
            [1] => ll
            [2] => et
        )

    [kr_four] => Array
        (
            [0] => yy
            [1] => qq
            [2] => ey
        )

    [ten] => 10
    [eleven] => 11
    [twelve] => 12
)
<pre>
```

To produce the array,i cloned 2 using the `five crud` button and 3 using the `nine_crud` button.Each cloned form has four fields.The problem with the array produced is that,each cloned forms fields are badly split and do not appear together(field 1 to field 4) as an array.For instance in this array

```
[kr_one] => Array
    (
        [0] => tt
        [1] => pp
        [2] => er
    )

[kr_two] => Array
    (
        [0] => rr
        [1] => oo
        [2] => en
    )

[kr_three] => Array
    (
        [0] => uu
        [1] => ll
        [2] => et
    )

[kr_four] => Array
    (
        [0] => yy
        [1] => qq
        [2] => ey
    )
```

in this array,i have three distinct cloned items but they don't appear as a single array.Is there something i can do for the fields in the single cloned box to appear as a unified array?.

Comment: If you want only one array, you have to put the same `name` attribute to every cloned box. That is `name='kr[]'` for the four boxes. Then in PHP you'll get an array of twelve values if you cloned 3 times

Comment: Oh thanks.That was indeed the problem.Could you kindly add that as the answer?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only one array, you have to put the same `name` attribute to every cloned box. That is `name='kr[]'` for the four boxes.

Then in PHP you'll get an array of twelve values if you cloned 3 times. Something like this:

```
[kr] => Array
(
    [0] => tt
    [1] => rr
    [2] => uu
    ....
    ....
    [11] => ey
)
```